# How can I make a reservation for hours only? django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a reservation site. I want the reservation to be made in hours only. For example, I don't want anyone to book from 10:30 to 12:00.
i want to be 10:00 to 12 or else just by hours

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZeJG.jpg)

How can I remove this minute column or make it zero by zero? lock at the image

my models is  :

```
from_hour = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
to_hour = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

my forms :

```
class Meta:
    model = OpeningHours

    fields = ('from_hour', 'to_hour','timing',)
    widgets = {
        'from_hour':forms.DateTimeInput(format=('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),attrs={'type':'datetime-local','class':'form-control'}),
        'to_hour':forms.DateTimeInput(format=('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),attrs={'type':'datetime-local','class':'form-control'}),
```

Comment: `select date_trunc('hour', now());  2023-10-18 12:00:00-07`. From [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

Comment: i dont understand you how can i do this i want more explain

Comment: A good place to start would be the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Comment: A datetime/timestamp is going to have minutes and seconds. If you want to have guaranteed  hour only resolution you will need to force those values to 0. I showed that from Postgres end. If you want to do that from Python end then: `datetime.datetime.now().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 18, 13, 0)`. Or see if your datetime input widget has a configuration setting to force the datetime to hour resolution.

Comment: For reservations it's much easier to use tsrange or tstzrange datatypes. This gives you the option to create a constraint to avoid double bookings. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html